# Paypal payout return statutes - How to handle?

Tags: paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I'm building a system to pay some users using the payouts API.
For Success and Failure cases I don'y have any problem, but there are a series of Transaction statuses in the documentation that I don't know how to handle.
Those are BLOCKED, NEW, ONHOLD and PENDING. My main doubt, is that if money is taken from my account in those cases.
I need to track in my DB if the payment was done or not, and if I ever get one of this statutes I'll have no idea if the money was taken or not, and if it was taken, how can I be notified when the user gets it. Or do I have to track it manually?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

My plan (not yet tested) is the following:

1. Upon creation of the request debit funds from Source Account.
2. If status updates to BLOCKED, DENIED, FAILED, REFUNDED, RETURNED then re-credit Source Account.

I think with this system the other Payout Item details are irrelevant.

Comment: so once recipient user trigger " REFUNDED OR RETURNED" , they can't change back to SUCCESS by capturing it, is this could be the case, just checking because I am not sure about it, also what is the difference b/t "REFUNDED", "RETURNED", I think both are doing the same thing.